# Решение проблем с обработчиками событий при копировании блока.

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Сразу говорю я в js слабоват. В общем вопрос в следующем есть блок. В нем есть форма которая обрабатывается через ajax. Я написал плагин который копирует данный блок в другое место (надо мне так, пример: http://jsfiddle.net/wre1bk27/). Соответсвенно он уже убивает все обработчики событий. Код там простой:

```
div = $(element).html();
innerdiv = '<li><span class="close"></span>'+div+'</li>';
$(innerdiv).insertAfter(ul.find('li').eq(el_num));
```

В общем намекните как сделать правильно. У меня там где форма вставляется блок с ID и при таком копировании я явно ломаю DOM.

Comment: @binliz, ничего он не убивает. Обработчики вешаются на конкретные элементы (не на селекторы! на существующие элементы), при просто копировании HTML в DOM возникает новый элемент - естественно, без обработчиков. Решения два - использование `.on()`, которое в данном контексте будет неверным, и использование [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), которое позволяет скопировать элемент с обработчиками.

Comment: хорошо я склонирую. дело в том что у меня получается каждая форма имее свой индификатор типа там id=BX_4954053 что то типа такого и по этому принципу оно и определяет блок который надо обрабатывать. Следсвенно у меня получается 2 одинаковых ИД?? Мне надо удалять старый? А потом при освобождении возвращать на место? Там плаги в примере (тоже я писал так что не пугайтесь).

Comment: @binliz а зачем у вас там id ? это чем-нибудь обусловлено ?

Comment: Да к сожалению обусловленно ajax компонентом из 1С Битрикс. Могу выдумать велосипед(типа послать данные на пустую страницу через обычный jquery но мне желательно склонировать код компонента т.к. о уже это умеет делать (в смысле данные из формы слать) чтобы его не выдумвывать.

Comment: Я в принципе понял следующее из комментариев. Мне надо склонировать блок, можно его очистить так как есть уже клон. А потом при сокрытии окна вернуть на место тоже клонированием. Это будет работать?

Comment: а почему просто не переместить блок ?

Comment: @eicto прошу прощения за свою безграмотность, вопрос стоит именно таким образом: я вот сделал так, я понимаю, что это неправильно. Дайте намек как это сделать. Вы даете ответ о перемещении блока. И меня это удовлетворяет (если действительно сохраняются все обработчики). Но как это делается я не знаю. Не сочтете вы за наглость если я вас попрошу сделать ваш комментарий ответом и дополнить его информацией о том как блоки переносятся (с примером) или ссылкой на сайт на котором это можно прочитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@binliz](/users/8664/binliz)](/users/8664/binliz) блок переносится например так (в вашем коде я немного запутался, поэтому сделаю отдельный пример) :

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s20yc9k7/ или так http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s20yc9k7/5/